# Wordpress - Rewrite rules and meta description

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem when I use '**add_rewrite_rule**' function in my `functions.php` file.

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^materiels/([a-z0-9-]+)/(vente|location)$/?','index.php?page_id=3&matos=$matches[1]&mode=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

The rewrite rule works fine but I have a problem with the meta tittle and meta description. The meta that appear in my HTML page is the meta entered in my Wordpress page not in my article linked by the rewrite rule.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked out this? http://www.paulund.co.uk/rewrite-urls-wordpress it has some useful info regarding meta information and custom urls